# Unable to Update an SKLabel Node using Swift 3 on button press

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to make a small game using SpriteKit. ( Xcode 8 and Swift 3 for iOS 10 )

I want to let the user pause the game when he touches the Pause text label. When he does that, I want to pause the game and change the label text to Unpause.

Below is my code for that part.

```
if ( pauseTextLabel.contains(touchLocation!)){
            gameLoopPaused = !gameLoopPaused;
            if ( pauseTextLabel.text == "Pause" ){
//                pauseTextLabel.text = "Unpause";
                pauseTextLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: gameData.fontName);
                initLabel(label: pauseTextLabel, gameData: gameData, text: "Unpause", pos: CGPoint(x: 3 * self.size.width/4 , y: self.size.height - 50 ) );
                self.addChild(pauseTextLabel);
                runPauseAction();
            } else {
                pauseTextLabel.text = "Pause";
                runUnpauseAction();
            }
        }
```

I tried doing this first, It didn't work.

```
if ( pauseTextLabel.contains(touchLocation!)){
            gameLoopPaused = !gameLoopPaused;
            if ( pauseTextLabel.text == "Pause" ){
                pauseTextLabel.text = "Unpause";
                runPauseAction();
            } else {
                pauseTextLabel.text = "Pause";
                runUnpauseAction();
            }
        }
```

I added a break point just before that block and this block shows no messages in the console. The game is being paused and I am able to resume it. However the only thing not working is the display text updating. I tried to remove it and add it to the view. It didn't work.

Any help or hints what went wrong is really appreciated.

Edit: 
I modified the touchesBegan as suggested. I am including my runPauseAction() to provide more information in case that matters.

```
private func runPauseAction(){
        print(#function);

        //self.pauseTextLabel.text = "Resume";
        self.view?.isPaused = true;
        self.physicsWorld.speed = 0.0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you pausing the whole scene/skView in

```
runPauseAction()
```

?

Try using an SKAction with delay to call the pause code like 0.1 seconds after changing the text label.

Also add the unpause method before the text label change.

```
runUnpauseAction()
pauseTextLabel.text = "Pause"
```

I would reccommend you create a worldNode in your gameScene for pausing.

```
let worldNode = SKNode()
```

than add it to the scene

```
addChild(worldNode)
```

and than add everything you need paused to that worldNode

```
worldNode.addChild(SOMENODE)
worldNode.addChild(SOMENODE2)
```

Than when you pause you call this

```
 worldNode.isPaused = true
 physicsWorld.speed = 0
```

and when you resume you call this

```
 worldNode.isPaused = false
 physicsWorld.speed = 1
```

This is a nicer way to pause your game, apple also does this in DemoBots. It also gives you more flexibility doing stuff, like overlaying menu nodes, when the game is paused.

I would also write your touches method like this.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = atPoint(location)

        if node == pauseTextLabel {
            if !gameLoopPaused {
                gameLoopPaused = true
                pauseTextLabel.text = "Unpause"
                runPauseAction()
            } else {
                runUnpauseAction()
                gameLoopPaused = false
                pauseTextLabel.text = "Pause"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I changed the touchesBegan function like you suggested. I still can't get the label to update. I included the pauseFunction in the question as it might be the one causing the issue. I looked at the DemoBots and would like to follow that format for my next project. But I would like to know what is causing this issue.

Comment: Is the label not updating for both or just when you want to resume?

Comment: I thought it was both. I just found out that they are in fact changing. I commented out the second part where I change it back from "Resume" to "pause" on unpausing the game. I can see the text change from "Pause" to "Resume" although only after I unpaused the game. Sorry if that was confusing. This isn't the behaviour I wanted..

Comment: Looks like it is changing. But it is not just reflecting that on screen before I pause it. Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can get past this?

Comment: Yeah you cannot change the text when a scene is paused. Non of the SpriteKit APIs like SKActions etc will work when the view is paused. Try to change your text label to "Resume" and than pause the scene. Than resume the game and change it back to "Pause". Thats why the world Node approach is better, it will take you 30-60 mins max. Just create the world node and add all the stuff you want pause to it (player, enemies, SKActions etc).

Comment: I was not able to that even if I tried to change the text before pausing.

Comment: If you comment the pause line and just try to change the text is it working?

Comment: It is working great. In the sense that, I was able to get it changing from "Pause" to "Resume" and "Resume" to "Pause". However, if I add the pausing logic, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah it must be the pausing the skview thing. Maybe it's getting called to fast. Try using an skaction with delay to call the pause code like 0.1 second after changing the text. Like I said you should really go for the worldNode approach.

Comment: Thank You!!  This was the issue and It is working now. I can't believe I haven't tried it. I thought Xcode/swift3 executes the commands linearly, one after the other. Guess I was wrong and understood that they may execute them simultaneously.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it's working. I will add that bit to my answer for future readers. Thanks for marking, happy coding.